# Problem passing commands on buttons created in for loop

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am trying to create menu and each button have to do different thing ( destroying frame and creating new one). Trying to pass different functions for each button in the loop .The problem is that the program execute only the last function for every button.

`

```
def salad():
        frame_left.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=3, sticky="WENS")
        frame_drinks.grid_forget()

    def meal():
        frame_drinks.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="WENS")
        frame_left.grid_forget()

    def new():
        salad()
        meal()
```

`

```
  for i, item in enumerate(item_photo_list):
        menu_button = tkinter.Button(frame_drinks, image=item, bg="yellow", command=new)
        row, column = divmod(i, COLUMNS)
        menu_button.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="news", padx=20, pady=20)
```

I try to use lambda and calling them from a list but it's the same as result.

The all code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import PhotoImage, NW, NO, RIGHT, LEFT, CENTER, TOP, ttk, NE, W
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Order System")
root.geometry("960x500")
root.config(background="#088a88")

frame_drinks = tkinter.Frame(root, background="red")
frame_drinks.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="WENS")

frame_left = tkinter.Frame(root, background="lightblue")
frame_left.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=3, sticky="WENS")

def salad():
    frame_left.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=3, sticky="WENS")
    frame_drinks.grid_forget()

def meal():
    frame_drinks.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="WENS")
    frame_left.grid_forget()

def new():
    salad()
    meal()

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=5)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

frame_drinks.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_drinks.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame_drinks.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
frame_drinks.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

frame_drinks.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_drinks.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame_drinks.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

frame_left.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame_left.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_left.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame_left.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
frame_left.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
frame_left.rowconfigure(4, weight=4)

# mid
COLUMNS = 4

photo_salad = Image.open(
    "salad.png"
)
photo_meal = Image.open(
    "meal.png"
)
photo_soda = Image.open(
    "soda.png"
)
photo_drinks = Image.open(
    "drinks.png"
)
photo_dessert = Image.open(
    "dessert.png"
)

photo_salad = photo_salad.resize((105, 85))
photo_meal = photo_meal.resize((105, 85))
photo_soda = photo_soda.resize((105, 85))
photo_drinks = photo_drinks.resize((105, 85))
photo_dessert = photo_dessert.resize((105, 85))

photo_salad = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo_salad)
photo_meal = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo_meal)
photo_soda = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo_soda)
photo_drinks = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo_drinks)
photo_dessert = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo_dessert)

item_photo_list = [photo_salad, photo_meal, photo_soda, photo_drinks, photo_dessert]


for i, item in enumerate(item_photo_list):
    menu_button = tkinter.Button(frame_drinks, image=item, bg="yellow", command=new)
    row, column = divmod(i, COLUMNS)
    menu_button.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="news", padx=20, pady=20)


bill = ttk.Treeview(frame_left, selectmode="browse")
bill.grid(row=4, column=0, rowspan=3, sticky="WENS")

bill["columns"] = ("1", "2")
bill["show"] = "headings"

bill.column("#0", width=100)
bill.column("# 1", minwidth=50, width=100)
bill.column("# 2", minwidth=50, width=100)

bill.heading("#0", text="")
bill.heading("# 1", text="Table")
bill.heading("# 2", text="Bill")

bill.insert("", "end", values=("name", "price"))
bill.insert("", "end", values=("name", "price"))

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  What is `item_photo_list`?  What is `frame_drinks`?  Without having all of your code, I can only guess at what you want.  You could include function references in a list, much like you would with lambdas, and use `i` to assign a different function from the list to each menu item.  You don't have to use lambdas...you can just do, for example, `actions = [new, salad, meal, ...]`.

Comment: @CryptoFool Can you give me example with code . Thank you

Comment: you can create a dictionary that stores each of the buttons functions as the values and their list index as the key, then when you iterate through the loop assign the dictionary value as the callback. that way you are not overwriting the previous reference on each iterattion